# How to overcome locations field caught empty in validated data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've a model:

```
class ListingPrice(Timestamps):    
    price = models.ForeignKey("Price", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey("location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["price", "location"]

class Price(Timestamps):

    package = models.ForeignKey("products.Package", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField("location", through="ListingPrice")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=3)
```

with a serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = LocalizedField()

    class Meta:
        model = location
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = LocationSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Price
        fields = ['package', 'locations', 'price']
        def create(self, validated_data):
             print("validated_data, validated_data)
```

and viewset:

```
class PriceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    ordering = ['id']
    permissions = {
        "GET": ["view_minimum_listing_price", ],
        "POST": ["add_minimum_listing_price", ],
        'PUT': ['update_minimum_listing_price', ],
        'DELETE': ['delete_minimum_listing_price', ],
    }
```

In testing I'mm using the following:

```
data = {
            "price": 12,
            "package": self.package.id,
            "is_enabled": False,
            "locations": [{'name': self.location.name, 'id': self.location.id}]
        }

response = self.client.post(path=self.url, data=data, format='json')
```

locations appear as empty dict in validated_data?
I need to caught it and added it to the price by locations.add. how to implement this?

Comment: You used `read_only` for `locations`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem with read_only=True, the field doen't show in validated_data. With it = False, the field does show in validated_data, but as empty dict

Comment: another problem is that you submit the data as `location`, not `locations` (plural).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's atypo here. still the same behaviour!